# How to change nginx document root on AWS Lightsail?

Tags: laravel, nginx, amazon-lightsail

I have setup an AWS Lightsail server running LEMP.

I adding a demo app for laravel and want to change the document root of the ngnix server so that the main website goes to /myapp/public which is the public directory for the laravel app.

Is there any guidance on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to edit the Nginx configuration. Ubuntu 18 + Nginx the file is located at /usr/nginx/sites-available/default. Many frameworks are like this and require some editing of the default web directory.